# c# Messagebox for touchscreen

Tags: c#, messagebox, pixelsense

I need a touch enabled message box for a surface 2.0 application. The standard `MessageBox.Show()` has to be confirmed with a mouse click.

That is not what I want.

I could write a small `UserControl`, but I wonder if there is something already integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself, after searching nearly an hour or so ^^

```
public partial class MsgBoxTouch : SurfaceWindow
    {
        public TouchBox1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();                

        }

        private void Button_TouchEnter(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}

<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="MsgBoxTouch"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 


    WindowState="Normal" WindowStyle="None" Width="300" Height="300">

    <Grid x:Name="Layout">

        <Button Content="OK" Height="50" TouchEnter="Button_TouchEnter">

        </Button>
    </Grid>
</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MessageDialog` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) to represents a dialog.

Comment: I see Surface/Metro. I'm developing for Microsoft Surface 2.0. So it doesn't fit , but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[blip-surface](http://code.google.com/p/blip-surface/) uses a MessageBox user control maybe you can use something similar to that

http://code.google.com/p/blip-surface/source/browse/trunk/Blip/UI/Controls/?r=28